# Enumerating 1-dimensional walks

Tags: random-walk

I've invented a thought experiment for myself, which is defined below:

> A robot walks on a 1-dimensional number line, with stride length 1. In
>   any instant, he may stay put (+0), walk left (-1), or walk right (+1).
>   For $n$ movements of the robot, enumerate the possible walks $W$ which
>   result in the robot returning to where he started.

So far, I've found the following:

- For $n=1$, $|W|=1$
- For $n=2$, $|W|=3$
- For $n=3$, $|W|=7$

For $n \geq 4$, enumeration becomes more difficult as now 2 pairs of "switch-backs" are possible instead of just 1.

Any ideas? Is there a general solution?

Comment: I haven't though about it yet.  But one initial thought is from any walk $w$ in $n-1$ returning to starting point, you can get a walk in $n$ by adding "stay put" (+0) before or after any of the steps in $w$.  Similarly, any walk in $n-2$ can be used to recover a walk in $n$ by adding a $(-1)$ somewhere and a $(+1)$ somewhere.  Not sure if these will lead you to any substantial solution

Comment: After writing a Python script, I have a few more results for analysis:
$n = 4$, $|W| = 19$

$n = 5$, $|W| = 51$

$n = 6$, $|W| = 141$

Comment: @InterstellarProbe Unfortunately, $n=4$ gives 19, so it breaks that pattern.

Comment: There are other things you could potentially use to exploit parity. The fact that $(+0)$ is equivalent to any pair of $(+1)$ and $(-1)$.  Or that steps to the left and to the right must occur in equal numbers.  Probably you have to break it up into cases when $n$ even and when $n$ odd

Comment: https://oeis.org/A002426

Comment: (This comment got sniped by the previous one, but may be useful as method.) A useful resource for such problems is the [Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](https://oeis.org/). Your sequence evidently proceeds as 1,3,7,19,51,141..., which yields [two](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C3%2C7%2C19%2C51%2C141&sort=&language=english&go=Search) possible hits. If we look at the first entry in the search [A002426](https://oeis.org/A002426), then one indeed finds this problem listed as an application (see Emeric Deutsch's second comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's treat a walk as a sequence of letters L,S,R where L represents moving to the left, S represents saying put, and R represents a move to the right. For a walk $w$, define: $|w|_L, |w|_S, |w|_R$ to be the number of times $L$, $S$, and $R$ appear in the walk respectively. Obviously, you have $|w|_L+|w|_S+|w|_R = |w| = n$. But, you also have $|w|_L=|w|_R$ because every left move requires a right move to "undo" it and every right move requires a left move to "undo" it.

Let $a,b\in \mathbb{N}$. Define $W_{a,b} = \{w: |w|_L = |w|_R= a, |w|_S = b\}$.

It is easy to calculate $|W_{a,b}|$ since it is the number of permutations of the multiset $\{L\cdot a, S\cdot b, R\cdot a\}$ which is $\dfrac{(2a+b)!}{(a!)^2b!}$

So, you are looking for:

$$|W|_n = \sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor \dfrac{n}{2}\right\rfloor} \left|W_{k,n-2k}\right| = \sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor \dfrac{n}{2}\right\rfloor} \dfrac{n!}{(k!)^2(n-2k)!}$$

Example:

$$|W|_4 = \sum_{k=0}^2 \dfrac{4!}{(k!)^2(n-2k)!} = \dfrac{4!}{4!}+\dfrac{4!}{(1!)^2(2!)}+\dfrac{4!}{(2!)^2(0!)} = 1+12+6=19$$

In terms of hypergeometrics, you have:

$$|W|_n = {_2}F_1\left(\dfrac{1-n}{2},-\dfrac{n}{2};1;4\right) = 3^n\cdot  {_2}F_1\left(\dfrac{1}{2},-n;1;\dfrac{4}{3} \right)$$

Here is [Wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Table%5BHypergeometric2F1%5B%281-n%29%2F2%2C-n%2F2%3B1%3B4%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C20%7D%5D) calculating the first 20 terms of the sequence.

More information on this sequence can be found [Here](https://oeis.org/A002426)